# How can I see actual browser window launched when I am running test cases on Remote Machine using Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, webdriver

I am running tests on remote ubuntu machine using jenkins. I can access this machine via putty.exe.
I want to see actual browser launched on particular port.

I am using java1.7+maven3+testng6.5. Selenium jars - 2.34.0, 2.35.0. Firefox is execuatable for all users by giving 777 permission.

I tried :

```
DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
            capability.setCapability("platform", Platform.LINUX);
            capability.setCapability("binary", "usr/bin/firefox");

            try {
                driver= new RemoteWebDriver(
                        new URL("http://staging.mywebsite.com:8083/wd/hub"), 
                        capability.firefox());
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        driver.get(productionurl);
```

**Error:**

```
Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
```

Comment: I need to ask the obvious here but are running the hub, anywhere on your network, and node-role on your remote station?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer in steps:
     1. Create hub on and node on your local machine
     2. Open console by typing `http://localhost:4444/grid/console`

3. Check the ip address on which hub is created(actualy its your ipaddress)

4. Run the remote code via jenkins:

```
 try {
                driver= new RemoteWebDriver(
                        new URL("http://ipadress_in_step_3:your_port/wd/hub"), 
                        capability.firefox());
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

PS: These steps would work as long as your "hub n node" are running which was started in step 1.

Answer (score 0):

Just by reading the trace: it seems that the port you try to connect is blocked on your staging machine. Configure your firewall so that port 4444 or 8082 allows tcp connections.